# Is there a way to increase the maximum zoom level?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I find the overhead view in *Dragon Age: Origins* useful for commanding my party members during harder battles.

The problem is that the maximum height is very low, so you can't see very far in this mode.

Is there a console trick or mod to adjust it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been a lot of discussion about mods (PC version, anyway) that can modify the camera angles and distances, but to my knowledge there has yet to be one created that successfully changes those.

[Source](https://fextralife.com/forums/t147970/free-camera-mod/)